# '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'?

Tags: python

[stuctured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuLIJ.png) [unstructured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbR6h.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyhZT.png)Ive got my code pretty much where i want it but for some reason i cant seem to get past this one error.

here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import re
df=pd.read_csv("Tweets.csv")

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    sor=row[:-1].sort_values(ascending=False)[:4]
    list.append(list(sor.index))

df['Tdidf_theme']=list

df.to_csv("Tweet_structured.csv")
```

and when i go to run i get

> '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

what am i missing?

im not really sure what to try

Comment: Are the values you're sorting a mix of strings and numbers? Note that `list` is a Python built-in so don't use it as the name of a local variable.

Comment: Does the trackback give you which line is giving the error? and Have you try to check the type of each object? I assume the error was at the line you try to sort the items in list.

Comment: Just a added point, if the list you try to sort is mixed with `str` and `int`, you may want to try converting the `int` to string first (i.e. by using `str()`)

Comment: @jimmymcheung im honestly not really sure what to do to fix this i appreciate the comments but i don't really know how to implement the changes you are all suggesting

Comment: @jarmod How would i make this change which is the local variable that i should change from list to something else and what do i change it to?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add a couple of rows from the CSV to your post. On the `list` point, make up a variable name e.g. `results` and write code like: `results = []` to declare and initialize the variable and then later use `results.append(somevalue)` to append a value to that variable.

Comment: The only place that would use `<` is the call to `sort_values`. I suspect one of the rows is a mix of `int` and `str` values.

Answer (score 0):

This message suggests, that you try to compare a string object (str) with an integer (int). The expression

Therefore, you cannot directly compare it with the number. If you want to compare the length of the entry, you can use the pandas.Series.str.len() operation.

If this field should actually contain an integer, you can use this method (pandas.to_numeric) to cast it from str to int.

If you rename the built in python list to some other values, Its seems to work. You can try that

Or you can convert those column type like below -
some strings and some integers. You can treat the integers as strings by converting the column to type string before doing the sort

```
df['sort_col'] = df['sort_col'].astype(str)
df.sort_values(by='sort_col', ascending=True, inplace=True)
```

In your data, add below lines before the for loop -

```
df['tweet_id'] = df['tweet_id'].astype(str)
df['airline_sentiments_confidence'] = df['airline_sentiments_confidence'].astype(str)
```

Comment: where would i put str()) and what exactly goes in the brackets?

Comment: Instead of using list.append(list(sor.index)), just declare a list above for loop and use that list variable to append values

Comment: li = []
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        sor=row[:-1].sort_values(ascending=False)[:4]
        li.append(list(sor.index))

    df['Tdidf_theme']=li
    df.to_csv("Tweet_structured.csv")

Comment: ive made this change but still get 

'<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Comment: ive added a screen shot of the file for reference if that helps

Comment: is this what you mean 

li = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    
    sor=row[:-1].sort_values(ascending=False)[:4]
    li.append(list(sor.index))

df['sort_col'] = df['sort_col'].astype(str)
df.sort_values(by='sort_col', ascending=True, inplace=True)    
df['Tdidf_theme']=list

df.to_csv("Tweet_structured.csv")

Comment: Use below lines before for loop -

df['tweet_id'] = df['tweet_id'].astype(str)
df['airline_sentiments_confidence'] = df['airline_sentiments_confidence'].astype(str)

Comment: is this correct?
i am still getting  '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'


li = []


for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df['tweet_id'] = df['tweet_id'].astype(str) 
    df['airline_sentiment_confidence'] = df['airline_sentiment_confidence'].astype(str)
    sor=row[:-1].sort_values(ascending=False)[:4]
    li.append(list(sor.index))

df['Tdidf_theme']=list

df.to_csv("Tweet_structured.csv")

Comment: you need to add those lines before for loop, try below code -

li = []
    df=pd.read_csv("Tweets.csv")
    df['tweet_id'] = df['tweet_id'].astype(str)
    df['airline_sentiment_confidence'] = df['airline_sentiment_confidence'].astype(str)
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        sor=row[:-1].sort_values(ascending=False)[:4]
        li.append(list(sor.index))
    df['Tdidf_theme']=list
    df.to_csv("Tweet_structured.csv")

Comment: i believe this seemed to work but im not really seeing much of a difference between the original file and the new one ive added screen shots of the structured vs unstructured. does this look right?

Comment: Well, In that case you need to check the requirement or logic you have used for sorting.

Comment: does it not look right? im not sure what other logic needs to be there

Comment: If you want to sort on the basis of multiple columns, you can use - 

df.sort(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], ascending=[False], inplace=True)

Comment: so would i delete sor=row[:-1].sort_values(ascending=False)[:4]

and replace it with 

 df.sort(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], ascending=[False], inplace=True)

its says 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sort'

Comment: use - 

df.sort_values(by=['col1', 'col2'], ascending=False, inplace=True)

Comment: when i use this i get an error saying 

'col1'

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    
    df.sort_values(by=['col1', 'col2'], ascending=False, inplace=True)
    li.append(list(sor.index))

df['Tdidf_theme']=list

df.to_csv("Tweet_structured.csv")

Comment: @VictorM , Inplace of col1, col2,....you have to put your own columns. I have used those col1, col2 for example